# Различие между relocatable и shared object

Tags: elf, linux

[Нашел](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) классификацию ELF-файлов на relocatable, executable и shared object.
В чём отличие между первым и последним?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relocatable - это перемещаемый объектный файл, который может быть скомпонован с другими объектными файлами, shared - особый вид перемещаемого объектного файла, который может быть загружен в память и динамически связан с другими модулями либо при загрузке, либо во время исполнения.

Comment: То есть в случае relocatable используется только статическая линковка, а в случае shared -- только динамическая?

Comment: Верно. Я советую почитать седьмую главу книги "Компьютерные системы: архитектура и программирование" Рэндала Брайанта и Дэвида О'Халларона. Web draft (на английском языке) доступен, например, здесь: http://www-di.inf.puc-rio.br/~endler/courses/inf1612/temp.pdf. В сети легко найти сканы английского и русского изданий.

Comment: Тогда, кажется, ваш ответ противоречит [другому найденному мной ответу][1]. "A Relocatable library is another word for a dynamic library."

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2246926/897090

Comment: Я не согласен с "другим ответом". Термин relocatable здесь как раз характеризует "обычный" объектный файл. Он содержит секции .rel.text и .rel.data, содержащие списки адресов, которые должны быть модифицированы, когда компоновщик объединит объектные файлы. Компилятор же не знает реальных абсолютных адресов, поэтому использует просто смещения от начала секции (видно в файлах листинга). См. раздел 7.4.

Поэтому в этом вопросе, я предпочитаю больше доверять профессорам университета Карнеги-Меллон Брайанту и О'Халларону. Кстати, автор того вопроса приводит цитату из вышеупомянутой книги.

Comment: [Здесь](http://mech.math.msu.su/~zubr/library.html) коротко и по делу. 

Обращаю внимание на необходимость создания позиционно-независимого (gcc -fPIC -c ...) кода, который будет включаться в shared (.so) объект.

Comment: Угу. Подозреваю, что неверное толкование термина relocatable основано на путанице с термином position-independent code.

PIC, как правильно замечено выше необходим для возможности загрузки в произвольную область памяти и динамического связывания (возможно, с несколькими экземплярами исполняемых объектных файлов).

Comment: А перемещение (relocation) - просто одна из двух основных функций компоновщика, который, склеивая одноименные секции объектных файлов, расставляет их в определенном порядке (перемещает), и, следовательно, пересчитывает относительные адреса, опираясь на сведения .rel.text (относительные адреса в коде) и .rel.data (относительные адреса глобальных объектов данных).